# An object in an array is displayed as [Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to print an array of objects which can also contain arrays of objects.

```
var courses = new Array(1)
  .fill()
  .map(function (element, index) {
    return {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name',
        grades: [
          { course_id: 1, grade: 2 },
          { course_id: 2, grade: 5 },
    ],
    }})

console.log(courses)
```

This code prints

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'Name', grades: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

an output in VSCode (Code Runner).
But I need

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'Name', grades: [ { course_id: 1, grade: 2 }, { course_id: 2, grade: 5 } ] } ]
```

What exactly am I missing? In the browser console works correctly, but I need it in VSCode. Thanks!

Comment: try: `console.log(JSON.stringify(courses, undefined,2))`

Comment: @sergio-tx it's ok, but i need an object

Comment: Do not confuse VS Code with the program you told VS Code to use to run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir) instead of `console.log` shows you the objects properties as well.

The option `depth: null` is needed for unlimited depth.

```
var courses = new Array(1)
  .fill()
  .map(function (element, index) {
    return {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name',
        grades: [
          { course_id: 1, grade: 2 },
          { course_id: 2, grade: 5 },
    ],
    }})

console.dir(courses, {depth: null})
```

Output in VSCode terminal:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name',
    grades: [ { course_id: 1, grade: 2 }, { course_id: 2, grade: 5 } ]
  }
]
```

Tested with VSCode version 1.71.0